# Using for loops with event listeners: How do i intepret it?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Code(taken from MDN)

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = bgChange();
  }
}
```

i++ is executed after each iteration, and from my understanding each iteration occurs when a "click" event occurs on any div. So i have two question: (1) Since the variable "i" updates each time i click, why is it i can keep pressing the divs(infinitely) and the onClick function will still execute? (2) I actually dont quite understand this code, since i starts at 0 why is it that when i click on other divs the onClick function still executes?

Really have no idea how to intepret this code and its in the introduction to events in MDN lol. Any help appreciated =)

Comment: This example basically says to grab all `div` elements and assign an `onclick` event handler to each of those elements. This only happens once, but once event handlers are assigned to all `div` elements, they will trigger every time you click on those `div`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i++ is executed after each iteration, and from my understanding each iteration occurs when a "click" event occurs on any div.

No. Each iteration ends when the event handler is **assigned**, not when it is triggered.

When the click happens is irrelevant. The loop rapidly goes through all the elements to set up something to happen **when** they are clicked.

You could see this by adding a console.log statement inside the loop.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  console.log(`About to assign event handler to div ${i}`);
  divs[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = bgChange();
  }
}

function bgChange() { return "red"; }
```

```html
<div>***</div>
<div>***</div>
<div>***</div>
<div>***</div>
<div>***</div>
```

Note that div elements are not interactive. They don't appear in the focus order. Screen readers don't announce them as being something you can click on. If you want something to click on, use a `<button type="button">...</button>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop iterates over all divs and adds a click handler on each div.

Comment: The IIFE is not needed when `let` is used in the for loop

Answer (score -2):

Your understanding [of a ***for loop***] is not quite right. When you click i always starts at 0 and the script repeats - so i increases by 1 (i++) until it is the length of *divs*. Then it continues to any code after the for loop. It does not perform 1 action and then wait until another click. *divs* will be an array that identifies all < div > elements on the page.

Comment: There's nothing repeating in this code - the `for` loop only runs once and assigns event handlers to each `div` element. Then those `event handlers` are executed every time you click on a particular `div`.

Comment: The is a terrible explanation. The click does not change value of `i`

Comment: The explanation was in reference to the for loop as Wesley's understanding of a for loop is off. Hindsight, I probably could of referenced that in what I was saying...